# How can I direct an href inside the same page in a frame

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</style>

<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
  <button id="find-me">Show my location</button><br/>
  <p id="status"></p>
  <a id="map-link" target="_self"></a>
  <script>
    function geoFindMe() {

      const status = document.querySelector('#status');
      const mapLink = document.querySelector('#map-link');

      mapLink.href = '';
      mapLink.textContent = '';

      function success(position) {
        const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        const longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        status.textContent = '';
        mapLink.href = `https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}`;
        mapLink.textContent = `Latitude: ${latitude} °, Longitude: ${longitude} °`;
      }

      function error() {
        status.textContent = 'Unable to retrieve your location';
      }

      if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        status.textContent = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser';
      } else {
        status.textContent = 'Locating…';
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
      }

    }

    document.querySelector('#find-me').addEventListener('click', geoFindMe);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Basically what I want is something like this: [Maps](https://www.maps.ie/coordinates.html)

to take this href from code and to open it on the same page under the say of the latitude and longitude that I get.
but I don't know how to do it, I tried using target self, and it doesn't do what I want to.

i tried the suggestion of using iframe, but the src doesn't work with this it says that the url refuses to connect.

Comment: Whith this code, what error you are gettig now? Doesn't work?
I seems that it shold work fine.

Comment: @Vahid
without iframe, it is working fine, but if i am trying to make it into iframe and put the link of the href into src then it says:
"www.openstreetmap.org refused to connect."
i can also take a print screen if needed.
(it works fine but i want to make it into an iframe or something and not open in another tab, or current tab, i want it to be displayed after clicking on latitude and longitude

Answer (score 0):

These are the ways you can try

### With on load event handler get lat and lan and pass to tags.

1. Take embedded code from the maps that with the iframe
2. Add src link in iframe and load map

Comment: Do you mean, use an onload even with the function of geoFindMe ?
and then what did u mean embedded code? like taking an iframe of the link i showed at the begging?
and when i tried before adding src link in my iframe it turned to not work, but first ill try understand what you meant about and then ill try again with adding the src link in the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Because of a cross-site request problem openstreetmap doesn't let you embed your link in a frame, you should use another type of link.

this is not allowed:
`https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=4/37.70/-111.74`

You may use a link like this: (With or without a marker)

```
https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=8.515777587890627%2C50.08600526783601%2C8.781509399414064%2C50.17997621067504&layer=mapnik&marker=50.13301380722123%2C8.648643493652344
```

in a iframe like this:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=8.515777587890627%2C50.08600526783601%2C8.781509399414064%2C50.17997621067504&layer=mapnik&marker=50.13301380722123%2C8.648643493652344" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>
```

You allowed only to display a box in a frame and you should provide four numbers (not a center point)
bbox=,,,

Comment: Indeed using this link of urs works with the iframe, but i dont understand what did u mean saying you should provide four numbers(not a center point)
Also now that i am using this link, i have no use for the
```mapLink.href = `https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/${latitude}/${longitude}`;```
and if not then how am i supposed to get the latitude and longitude
(also thanks alot for helping)

Comment: If you go to this link openstreetmap.org/#map=4/37.70/-122.72 and click on the share link at the right side of the screen and there, click on the html blue link, you would get iframe sample under the html link, as I mentioned. For your code, you could add a small number to latitude and longitude which you get from navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error) to create maxLatitude and maxLongitude and also subtract a small number from latitude and longitude to create minLatitude and minLongitude.

Comment: In this way you will create a box that will shown in the iframe. This will simulate zoom level also, use bigger number for zoomout and small ones to zoomin. But if you want a total control over showing the map, then I suggest that you use a different approach and use OpenStreetMap javascript APIs. By the way, if you find this answer useful, please click on check-mark answer to accept the response. Thank you.